# Google Play Console: Include Devices Button is disable

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to include only Samsung phone to my app, but "Include Button" is disable. However "Exclude Button" is working.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQWiO.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPKRb.png)

Comment: Probably because they're already included

Comment: @user14678216 , I want my app only available on Samsung phones . How can I do that?

Comment: You would exclude the non Samsung phones, but you would have to do that regularly as new phones are added every day